# After Reboot kubenetes master node is not in Ready state

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I wondered when i restart my ubuntu machine on which i have setup kubernetes master with flannel. before reboot it's working fine. but after reboot master node is not in ready state.

I try to get node details using describe.

```
KubeletNotReady runtime network not ready: NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:docker: network plugin is not ready: cni config uninitialized
```

This error is printed in logs. i search about this and find some solutions like reinitialize flannel.yml but didn't work.

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/1031    As per provided solution here, reinstall docker in machine. that's works.
every thing works fine after reinstall docker on machine. Can any one explain me why this happend? as if i restart machine then every time i need to reinstall docker? or is there any other setting or configuration which i missing?
Thank you

Comment: are you rinning kubernetes locally on minikube. this can arise due to cluster issues.

Comment: @JoePauly, on local ubuntu machine using kubeadm i am running kubernetes, not on minikube

Comment: Did you try this "kubectl -n kube-system apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/bc79dd1505b0c8681ece4de4c0d86c5cd2643275/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml "

Comment: @JoePauly Yes, I tried that but didn't work. after that i just reinstall docker and start docker service and it's work.

Comment: Did you reinstall the same docker version? Which kubernetes/docker version are you using?

Comment: @acid_fuji Yes, i have reinstall same latest docker version. Kubernetes version is 1.17.2 and docker version 19.03.5 on ubuntu

Comment: Can you update question with `kubectl describe node` command output. Do you have anything  in your dir `/etc/cni/net.d` or is it empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the provided information there are couple of steps and points to be 
taken into consideration when you encounter this kind of issue:

First check is to verify if file `10-flannel.conflist` is not missing from `/etc/cni/net.d/`. You should have a file with this kind of information there:

```
{
 "name": "cbr0",
 "cniVersion": "0.3.1",
 "plugins": [
   {
     "type": "flannel",
     "delegate": {
       "hairpinMode": true,
       "isDefaultGateway": true
     }
   },
   {
     "type": "portmap",
     "capabilities": {
       "portMappings": true
     }
```

If your file is placed there please check if you specifically have `cniVersion` field there.
In some flannel deployments there was missing the `cniVersion` field.

Second troubleshoot check is too check `kubelet` logs. Kubelet could report some problems with not finding cni config.
You may find logs at: `/var/log/kubelet.log`

Also very useful is to check output of `journalctl -fu kubelet` and see if nothing wrong is happening there. 
In some cases restart `kubelet` might be helpful, you can do that using `systemctl restart kubelet`

If you suspect that the docker is causing a problem you can check docker logs in similar way you checked the kukubelet logs 
using `journalctl -ul docker`. If the docker is causing some issuse try to restart the docker service before reinstalling it 
using `sudo systemctl restart docker.service`

Finally it is really worth following exactly [official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/) with creating kubeadm clusters, espcially the pod [network section](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/#pod-network).
Please note that it is important to hold all the binaries to prevent them from unwanted updates. 
Kubernetes has also a very good [troubleshoot document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/troubleshooting-kubeadm/) regarding `kubeadm`.

Hope this helps.